# How to remove the default clickhouse user through users.d

Tags: settings, clickhouse

For a clickhouse production server, I would like to secure the access through a defined user, and remove the default user.

I'm using a users.d/myuser.xml file to add a new user, and I would like to remove the default user by this means too.

I can't find the right combination. It look like I should use the "remove" attribute, but it's not documented.

Comment: In my case, I remove old password in `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you need to do the next changes:

**/users.d/users.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
    <users>
        <default remove="remove">
        </default>
        
        <new_secured_user>
            <password>hello_world</password>
            <!-- More secure way to define password: --> 
            <!-- <password_sha256_hex>65e84be33532fb784c48129675f9eff3a682b27168c0ea744b2cf58ee02337c5</password_sha256_hex> -->
        </new_secured_user>  
    </users>
</yandex>
```

Look at the article [Remove/Replace config elements](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/configuration_files/).

---

Take into account that removing *default* user requires some modification of cluster configuration (see [Access Rights](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/access_rights/)):

> The default user is chosen in cases when the username is not passed.
> The default user is also used for distributed query processing, if the
> configuration of the server or cluster doesn't specify the user and
> password (see the section on the [Distributed engine](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/distributed/)).